# rails 4 - Customizing certain values when generating dropdowns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using `collection_select` to create a dropdown with a collection of object.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:outcome, @story.pages, :id, :title, {}, {class: "browser-default"}) %>
```

This gives me a dropdown with all the proper values for all the pages available in my `story`. The problem is that, I would like to be able to customize one particular value of the dropdown to say `This page`

So instead of getting

```
Dropdown
+--> Page 1
+--> Page 2
+--> Page 3
+--> Page 4
```

I would get this

```
Dropdown
+--> Page 1
+--> This page
+--> Page 3
+--> Page 4
```

if I was to show it on page 2.

How could I achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with collection_select, but what I think you'll have to do is make a method that will return an array with the desired output.

So something like:

```
class Story
def x_pages
    pages.map { |page| page == current_page ? "This page" : "Page #{page}"
end
```